# Webview throws ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED during logout

Tags: android, webview

I have an application that loads through webview. I am able to login into application which has been launched through webview. But during logout, it keeps throwing `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error for the server it is sending logout request against.

When I do the same login/logout in regular browser on mobile, i still get the same error on browser. 
When I do the same login/logout in regular browser on PC, it works perfectly fine.

Not entirely sure if this is a webview using Chromium client issue or issue with server?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Are you using any local server which is not accessible from outside network?

Comment: sounds like a server issue or a DNS issue. Please have a look at this post: https://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved, and consider posting some server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are facing this issue on both WebView & Mobile Web browser. This is certainly that **website server issue**.

Web applications generally decide many things based on UserAgent Sting of browser

- Which domain to redirect user?,  like **desktop.blablablablablabla.com** or **mobile.blablablablablabla.com**
- What should be layout of webpage
- What size of images should be served
- What media should be served
- and many other things

You can check your user agent string using **http://whatsmyuseragent.org/**
It will be different for Desktop PC & Mobile Web Browser

**Sample user agent strings**

**Desktop PC Browser:** *Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36*

**Mobile Browser:** *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; PLUS Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Mobile Safari/537.36*

To replicate issue on Desktop PC browser, you can use some **UserAgent Switcher plugin**, Switch to some mobile browser user agent and issue will be reproducible there as well

One such plugin for Firefox Desktop browser is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/